# Regular Expression for Japanese Full-Width Numbers Returning All Full Width Characters

Tags: php, regex, curl

I am writing a PHP file that takes the contents of a web page, filters for full-width numbers, and converts them to half-width. Currently, my program returns all full-width characters on the page, not just the numbers.

```
<?php
$fullwidthPattern = '/([０-９])/';

$handle = curl_init();
 
$url = (URL removed for privacy reasons);

function getFullWidth(string $input) {
    global $fullwidthPattern;
    return preg_match($fullwidthPattern, $input);
}

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
$output = curl_exec($handle);
 
curl_close($handle);

function jp_str_split($str) {
    $pattern = '/(?<!^)(?!$)/u';
    return preg_split($pattern,$str);
}

$jpContents = jp_str_split($output);

$numbers = array_filter($jpContents, 'getFullWidth');

foreach($numbers as $x) {
    echo $x;
}
```

My regular expression is currently '/([０-９])/', but I have also tried '/[０-９]/' and '/[０１２３４５６７８９]/'.

Comment: Note that you still process Unicode numbers, so the `u` flag is required, `$fullwidthPattern = '/([０-９])/u';`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately, adding the `u` flag causes the output to return as empty

Comment: Also, splitting is probably better done with `function jp_str_split($str) { preg_match_all('/\X/u', $str, $matches); return $matches[0]; }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, using the `u` flag and your update to the `jp_str_split` function solved the issue. Is it possible for you to explain what the difference is between my `jp_str_split` and the one you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting should be done with

```php
function jp_str_split($str) {
    preg_match_all('/\X/u', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0]; 
}
```

The `\X` construct matches any Unicode grapheme *in full*, your `(?<!^)(?!$)` regex matches *any* location inside the string, even between bytes regardless of the `u` flag presence (it affects the chars you consume and not the locations inside the matched string).

Also, since you process Unicode numbers, you must also pass the `u` flag in the second regex:

```php
$fullwidthPattern = '/([０-９])/u';
```